# mysql match against query

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysql match against query in my search query like this way

```
MATCH(film_name) AGAINST ('the vacation' IN BOOLEAN MODE).
```

But previously i use this one

```
film_name like '%the vacation%'
```

So my question is that i am getting the right result now by using match and against but the problem is that when i am using like there i can use the `%` sign before and after the search string so if the search string present with in the string then it was return the result so plz tell how to write my `" MATCH(film_name) AGAINST ('the vacation' IN BOOLEAN MODE) "` so that it also behaves `like '%'.

If the file name is 'rocketsingh'

then if i run `film_name like '%rocket%'` then it shows me the result

but if i run `MATCH(film_name) AGAINST ('rocket' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` then it will not show any result. Please suggest what to do.

Comment: In boolean mode searching for "the vacation" will search for film_name containing "the" or "vacation".  This might not give you the results that you're expecting...

Answer (score 2):

**MATCH** command allows only prefixed wildcards but not postfixed wilcards. Since single words are indexed, a postfix wildcard is impossible to manage in the usual way index does. You can't retrieve ***vacation** instantly from index because left characters are the most important part of index.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: You can't. The `MATCH AGAINST` operator matches words, not strings. There is a difference between the two. Also note that your example will also match `vacation`, `the`, `vacation the` or `the something something vacation` and other. You should read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) what searches you can do.

You should stick to your first option with `LIKE` if you don't want word searches.